Change log file for php-fpm
In order to have only one .log file related with php issues, I want to force php-fpm to write errors in /var/log/php-fpm/error.log instead of /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log.
I just updated /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and also /etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini and restarts php-fpm service, but I still getting errors in /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log.
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
...
; Default Value: nothing is defined by default except the values in php.ini and
;                specified at startup with the -d argument
;php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
;php_flag[display_errors] = off
;Comment by ME : php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
;Next line added by ME
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
...

/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini
...
; OPcache error_log file name. Empty string assumes "stderr".
; Comment by ME : opcache.error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
; Next line added by ME
opcache.error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
...

I'm on Rocky Linux 9.1
What am I missing?

Welcome, please [edit] the question adding the snippets of your configuration and what OS you are running, I guess is RHEL related?

@schrodingerscatcuriosity. Thanks. Please, could you take a look if question is now better formatted?
